# How to import Postman's collection into SoapUI?

Tags: postman, soapui, postman-collection

Maybe anyone known how can I import postman collection into the **SoapUI** rest project. I just find reverse import way here: http://blog.getpostman.com/2016/04/27/importing-soapui-projects-into-postman/

May be I should import Postman collection in intermediate state(for example `*.xml` or `*.json` format) and after that import in to **SoapUI**?

Comment: **2017**: Use SoapUI import menu. Postman must export as _Collection v1_ format. https://www.soapui.org/docs/postman-collections.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Smartbear developed a postman plugin for Ready!API:
https://github.com/SmartBear/readyapi-postman-plugin

Since the question is specifically about SoapUI, here are a few options:

- upgrade to Ready!API;
- get the trial version of Ready!API and import all your collections before the trial expires;
- adapt the source code from GitHub to generate a soapUI project (xml) file from the json postman export.

One thing to note, a project saved in Ready!API can be opened in SoapUI and vice-versa.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been years, but if someone has a similar problem, here is an explanation specifically for SOAPui and not by using ReadyAPI: https://www.soapui.org/docs/postman-collections.html
You also have to have the latest version 5.5 of SOAPui.